# How to put values in Map which is within a Map

Tags: java, dictionary

How do I put values in this map?

```
public static Map<String, TreeMap<String, SomeClass>> myMap=Collections.synchronizedMap(new TreeMap<String, TreeMap<String,SomeClass>>());
```

Comment: Put values into which `Map`?  The outer `Map` or one of the inner `TreeMaps`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to make sure the "inner map" exists, then you can put values into it:

```
String outerKey = "exampleKey1";
String innerKey = "exampleKey2";
SomeClass innerValue = new SomeClass();

TreeMap<String, SomeClass> innerMap = myMap.get(outerKey);
if (innerMap == null) {
  innerMap = Collections.synchronizedMap(new TreeMap<String, SomeClass>());
  myMap.put(outerKey, innerMap);
}
innerMap.put(innerKey, innerValue);
```

You should also consider changing the type to:

```
public static Map<String, SortedMap<String, SomeClass>> myMap = ...
//                        ^^^^^^^^^
```

or just `Map` depending on if you need the sorted property.

Answer (score 1):

```
TreeMap<String, SomeClass> map = myMap.get(key1)
if(map == null) {
  map = Collections.synchronizedMap(new TreeMap<String, SomeClass>());
  myMap.put(key1, map);
}
map.put(key2, value);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TreeMap<String, SomeClass> value = new TreeMap<String, SomeClass>();
myMap.put("key", value);
```